# Text and MathJax above symbol

Tags: support, mathjax

How can regular text and/or MathJax be positioned directly atop a MathJax symbol?

Example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85113/xrightarrow-text. The code there seems bootless on MSE?

Another (Abortive) Example : ${\mapsto}^{\text{text} \int} \qquad$ (Code : `{\mapsto}^{\text{text} \int}`).

`\mathops{\mapsto}^{\text{text} \int}` also fails.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\overset{\mbox{This?}}{\longrightarrow}$

`$\overset{\mbox{This?}}{\longrightarrow}$`

Answer (score 8):

If you want the arrow to stretch with the size of the text on top, try

```
$\xrightarrow{\text{text}\int}$
```

which produces: $\xrightarrow{\text{text}\int}$.

To get your original attempt to work in in-line math mode, you need to use `\limits` to force the superscript into the overset position:

```
$\mathop{\longmapsto}\limits^{\text{text}\int\strut}$
```

which produces $\mathop{\longmapsto}\limits^{\text{text}\int\strut}$, but the arrow here won't stretch.  I've added a `\strut` to give a little extra space between the arrow and text.

To get a stretchy arrow, you could use the non-standard `\Newextarrow` command from the `extpfeil` extension:

```
$\require{extpfeil}\Newextarrow{\xmapsto}{5,5}{0x27FC}$
$\xmapsto{\text{text}\int}$
```

which gives
$\require{extpfeil}\Newextarrow{\xmapsto}{5,5}{0x27FC}$
$\xmapsto{\text{text}\int}$.  Note that the first expression only needs to be done once.